# SQL Server CE Insert throws "Table name is not valid"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

I'm running into an issue inserting some data to a table on my SQL Server CE database. The end goal is to send the necessary values for columns X, Y,and Z so that I can perform an `INNER JOIN` to the table with another and then pull down column Q.

Here's my insert:

```
//Make the SQL query and set the parameters
SqlCeCommand SQLVarQ = connection.CreateCommand();

SQLVarQ.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Results (Value, Indx, Length) VALUES (@Var, @Ind, @Lng)";
SQLVarQ.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;

SQLVarQ.Parameters.Add("@Var", ThreadBuffer.SelectedText);
SQLVarQ.Parameters.Add("@Ind", ThreadBuffer.SelectionStart);
SQLVarQ.Parameters.Add("@Lng", Convert.ToInt32(varWordMatch.Length));

SQLVarQ.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.Both;

using (SQLVarQ)
{
   SQLVarQ.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
}
```

This is the error it's throwing:

> The specified table does not exist. [ INSERT INTO Results (Value,
>   Indx, Length) VALUES (@Var, @Ind, @Lng) ]

Anyone have any ideas as to why this would be happening? Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: I know I created the table because this is just above the other code snippet:

```
            SqlCeCommand SqlTable = connection.CreateCommand();
        SqlTable.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE Results (Value NVARCHAR, Indx INT, Length INT, Data NVARCHAR)";
        using (SqlTable)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("The Table already exists");
            }
        }
```

Comment: "anyone have any ideas as to why this would be happening?": well, probably because the table doesn't exist...

Comment: After a `using()` you don't need a Dispose() anymore. And never call GC.Collect() without a very good, very special reason.

Comment: Can you show what the actual SQL Server Connection string looks like in your .config file CommandType.TableDirect shouldn't that be CommandType.Text also..?

Comment: Personally I would  refactor that and wrap all that code inside of using (SqlCeConnection c = new SqlCeConnection(...) { } but that's your call

Comment: I can't add this as an answer for another 7 hours, but I found the issue was in I was connecting to the wrong database. Both of the databases have similar names and similar tables. (Different products have their own database) I know this was a stupid answer, but it worked. Thanks for the input everyone. If someone could add this as an answer, I will mark it for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you've set CommandType = `CommandType.TableDirect`. Try `CommandType.Text` instead.

Comment: @DJKRAZE - ok, didn't spot it in your comment

Comment: I tried removing the CommandType.TableDirect as well. No difference in error.

Comment: I can't mark this as an answer for another 7 hours, but I found the issue was in I was connecting to the wrong database. Both of the databases have similar names and similar tables. (Different products have their own database) I know this was a stupid answer, but it worked. Thanks for the input everyone. If someone could copy/paste this into an answer, I'll mark it for you.